# Grouping the list of numbers that have common.

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, list-manipulation, gathering

I am working on some simple problem. It is like puzzle..

Let's say I have some list

```
input={{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,4}}
```

Which means 1 can go and back to 1 (<->), 1<->2, 1<->3, 2<->3,3<->3 4<->4.
So I want to make some groups that can go and back, by grouping the elements if there is any connection

```
(*wishing*)output={{1,2,3},{4}}
```

Here is how I tried, it is little complicated way, and I could not finish this.. Sorry for messy code.

```
Do[g[i] = {}, {i, 1, Length[input]}];

out=Table[Table[
   If[input[[i, 1]] == input[[a, 1]], g[i] = Append[g[i], input[[a, 2]]]]
   , {a, 1, Length[input]}]
  , {i, 1, Length[input]}] /. Null -> Sequence[]
```

and I got

```
Table[Union[Flatten[out[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[out]}]
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3}, {3}, {4}}
```

So

```
Union[%]
{{3}, {4}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Which is almost... what I want to get, but I cannot... get what I want to get. I might be able to make it even masseir code.. but anyone have any tip?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know that you will answer that so quickly, Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
input = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
ConnectedComponents@Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ input]
(*  {{3, 1, 2}, {4}} *)
```

Comment: Your one-liner graph-theoretic answers always make me smile, +1.

Comment: Yep; that's the correct solution.

Comment: @ciao That's probably my main reason for hanging around :)

Comment: @user3002626 Please remember to accept one answer (no matter if it takes you a few days, but please don't leave the question "orphan")

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is 1000 times slower than `belisarius`'s and is likely to scale terribly. I post it only for the purpose of illustrating that a "transparent" approach can be easily implemented in one line in *Mathematica* (transparent meaning that the actual steps taken are basically shown, unlike the graph-theoretic function approach, which hides some of the algorithms under the hood; as `belisarius` once told me:

> The main problem when programming in Mma is finding a way without programming.

which is why their solution is so much better).

```
input = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
FixedPoint[Union@@@Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] &, input]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4}} *)
```

The function `Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &]` separates the list into sublists in which the elements fed pairwise to the function `! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &` yield `True`. For instance,

```
! DisjointQ[#1, #2] & @@ {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}
! DisjointQ[#1, #2] & @@ {{1, 1}, {4, 4}}
(* True *)
(* False *)
```

On a single pass, he function `Gather` won't collect all the pairs together that need to be paired:

```
Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] & @ inputs
(* {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{4, 4}}} *)
```

For this reason, we `Apply` `Union` to each of the sublists and try again:

```
Union@@@Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] & @ inputs
Union@@@Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] & @ %
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {4}} *)
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4}} *)
```

On longer lists with more than two connected components, it is likely that this will need to be run more than twice, which is why I employ `FixedPointList` to iteratively run `Union@@@Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] &` until all the connected points are gathered together. Part of the slowness of this method has to do with the fact that we run over the list multiple times.

---

For instance,

```
input = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {1000, 2}];
(* belisarius *)
ConnectedComponents@Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ input]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* march *)
FixedPoint[Union @@@ Gather[#, ! DisjointQ[#1, #2] &] &, input]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.001302, Null} *)
(* {3.513250, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I apology that I did not accept your answer.. I think your method is very helpful for me to understand mma. Thank you alot!

Comment: @user3002626. You don't need to apologize for accepting a *much much* better answer!